# Pandas: select last four dates from a cut-off level

Tags: pandas, date, datetime, grouping

Hi I have a list of dates and I want to look at the dates and if a date is between 1st of January and 31st of March, then select that date as the end date for that specific year and take the previous 4 dates as part of that year. (There are only 4 dates for each year, so there would never be 2 dates between the range I specified. )

My data looks like this:

```
         date
0        1995-03-15
1        1995-07-06
2        1995-09-13
3        1995-12-12
4        1996-03-14
5        1996-07-01
6        1996-09-17
7        1996-12-12
8        1997-03-13
9        1997-06-25
10       1997-09-10
11       1997-12-12
```

And I would like to have something like this (in a separate column)

```
          year
0         1994
1         1995
2         1995
3         1995
4         1995
5         1996
6         1996
7         1996
8         1996
9         1997
10        1997
11        1997
```

Among other things, I tried the following:

```
df['year'] = df.date.dt.to_period('A-MAR')
```

However, I was not able to pass a range between January and March...I was also thinking that I could maybe select only the month from the date column with: `df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month` and then do a function that select the last for rows from the date that is between [1 and 3] (including) and puts the year in another column??

Does anyone have any ideas about this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
y = df.date.dt.year
mask = df.date.dt.month.between(1, 3)
df['year'] = y.where(mask).bfill().fillna(y.max() + 1).sub(1).astype(int)
print (df)
         date  year
0  1995-03-15  1994
1  1995-07-06  1995
2  1995-09-13  1995
3  1995-12-12  1995
4  1996-03-14  1995
5  1996-07-01  1996
6  1996-09-17  1996
7  1996-12-12  1996
8  1997-03-13  1996
9  1997-06-25  1997
10 1997-09-10  1997
11 1997-12-12  1997
```

**Explanation**:

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) by months with [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for replace `NaN`s to not matched values:

```
print (y.where(df.date.dt.month.between(1, 3)))
0     1995.0
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        NaN
4     1996.0
5        NaN
6        NaN
7        NaN
8     1997.0
9        NaN
10       NaN
11       NaN
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

Then use back filling missing values:

```
print (y.where(df.date.dt.month.between(1, 3)).bfill())
0     1995.0
1     1996.0
2     1996.0
3     1996.0
4     1996.0
5     1997.0
6     1997.0
7     1997.0
8     1997.0
9        NaN
10       NaN
11       NaN
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

Missing values (last rows) are replaced by maximam year with added `1`:

```
print (y.where(df.date.dt.month.between(1, 3)).bfill().fillna(y.max() + 1))
0     1995.0
1     1996.0
2     1996.0
3     1996.0
4     1996.0
5     1997.0
6     1997.0
7     1997.0
8     1997.0
9     1998.0
10    1998.0
11    1998.0
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

Last subtract one year:

```
print (y.where(df.date.dt.month.between(1, 3)).bfill().fillna(y.max() + 1).sub(1))
0     1994.0
1     1995.0
2     1995.0
3     1995.0
4     1995.0
5     1996.0
6     1996.0
7     1996.0
8     1996.0
9     1997.0
10    1997.0
11    1997.0
Name: date, dtype: float6
```

Comment: @jerzrael, sorry to bother you. I have another question somewhat similar to the one above.. is there a way to select the closest date to 31st of March and make **that** the last date of the year and classify the previous 3 as part of the same year? (similar, but instead of looking at range, you look at the closest value before 31st of March)
(Should I submit another question?)

Comment: @Adrian - Can you create new question? Now I have no idea.